# FFmpeg Windows directshow filter

Tags: c++, filter, ffmpeg, directshow

I'm trying to open a directshow video source (webcam/push source) using the ffmpeg api however I'm not having any luck. 
I've tried using

```
av_open_input_file()
```

however I don't think this is the right way... Does anyone have any pointers?

I'm using visual studio and c++ on a windows system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use the ffmpeg API, but might help you with your video grabbing.

I found a [sample app on codeproject called LiveVideo](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/LiveVideo.aspx) that can grab video from a WebCam using DirectShow.  It's from 2004, but has classes that wrap the ever-inscrutable DirectShow API, which was massively helpful.  I was able to modify this project to simultaneously grab from two webcams on my XP laptop.

Comment: Seems like a decent project! however I was kind of hoping to use ffmpeg as I've already built some stuff using it that I was hoping to add on!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use DirectShow + ffmpeg wrapper for required output format? So, open webcam using DirectShow way, not ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=803&p=2983&hilit=avdevice_register_all#p2983 describes a bit more how to do that programmatically

Answer (score 0):

with ffmpeg , you can find your devices that have data ( video or audio ) .

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

In my case my output is below.

[image]

I can easily open this with this code.

```
ffplay -f dshow -i video="ManyCam Virtual Webcam":audio="Mikrofon (ManyCam Virtual Microphone)"
```

[image]

Also I can restream or save this output with ffmpeg. ( Note : the desktop screen also can be taken by this code )

my example is usage of ffmpeg build not the core lib. I don't have ffmpeg c++ lib now but I can show it with opencv ffmpeg merged project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You might also look at the [OpenCV examples](http://nashruddin.com/display-video-from-webcam-with-opencv.html).